How can I integrate time in my Implicit Feedback dataset?
I'm working on a recommendation system based on Collaborative Filtering. Specifically, I've been looking at models such as NCF (Neural Collaborative Filtering) and SAR (Simple Algorithm for Recommendation), and I see that most of these models exploit time data to make better predictions. For example, SAR applies a time decay function to the interaction, giving more weight to recent interaction than older ones. Indeed, many toy examples use the MovieLens dataset where's there a conveniently placed Timestamp column.
For my specific task, I have time information, but I can't see any way of using it for modeling. A user-service implicit feedback matrix is constructed by querying an interaction database, grouping by userID and serviceID, and counting the number of rows: that tells me how many times that user has requested that service (which is considered our implicit rating). However, user X can request service $Y$ at time $Z$, again at time $W$, then at time $S$, etc. So, time information is lost. One user can request many services multiple times, and one service can be requested multiple times by many users.
I've thought of several strategies to go around this problem:

Rather than aggregating all history, I could group interactions into time bins. For example, if I decided to group by quarters, I'd end up with rating_Q1, rating_Q2, etc.
Since I have access to all historical data with day-to-day granularity, and I've already performed seasonality analysis on many of the available services, I considered adding features to capture seasonal trends, however I have no idea on how to do that :)

Does anybody have any idea?
